# "Quadly" numbers with just 4 factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

A positive integer with exactly four positive factors is called "quadly". Compute the least $n$ for which each of $n,n+1$ and $n+2$ is quadly. (ARML 2008)

My method of attacking this problem started by first noting that for each quadly number the prime factorisation must be of the form $pq$ ($p$ and $q$ are unique prime factors) or $m^3$ (where $m$ is prime). Then I also noted since the 3 numbers are consecutive, one of them must have a factor of 3 and atleast 1 of them must have a factor of 2. We start off by assuming that $n$ is even and so it is of the form $2q$. Then $n+2$ must also be even and be of the form $2p$. Subtracting the two equations we get $2p-2q=2 \implies p=q+1$. This means that $p$ and $q$ are consecutive and they're both primes. This only gives the possibility that $(p,q)=(3,2)$. Plugging this back in we get that the three numbers are $4,5,6$ but $4$ and $5$ are clearly not quadly. Hence we have a contradiction and so $n$ must be odd which means that $n+1$ must be even. We also know that one of the three integers is also a multiple of 3. From here I kind of brute-forced my way by finding prime multiples of 2, i.e. finding $2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime and checking $2p-1$ and $2p+1$ to see if they were quadly or not. Doing so I found that for $p=17$ yields the first solution of three consecutive quadly numbers which is $33,34,35$.

However, I'm looking for a more systematic approach which instead of using brute force for the rest of the problem, actually derives the answer mathematically. I'm sure there is a way to do but I can't think of one. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Restrictions for numbers a , a+1 and a+2  all having exactly 4 divisors :

$n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)$

$n^3-1=(n-1)(n^2+n+1)$

If n is an odd prime, then n-1 and n+1 are even numbers and $n^2-n+1 \ge 2$, so
neither $n^3-1$ nor $n^3+1$ can have exactly 4 divisors, if n>3. Since 27 and
8 are also not involved in a triple, the 3rd powers do not need to be considered.

The remaining cases lead to the equation

$$3u - 2v = 1$$

or

$$3u - 2v = -1$$

where u and v are primes greater than 3.

The first equation has the solution

$$u=2n+1 , v = 3n+1$$

for some natural number n.

The second equation has the solution

$$u = 2n+1 , v = 3n + 2$$

for some natual number n.

Maybe these restrictions help you.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you do the search, you may probably cut corner before that.

Excluding the possibility of very small numbers ($<5$), as you mentioned, 3 consecutive numbers have at least 1 of them even. So it must be the format of $2p$, where $p$ is a prime. Since $4|2p-2, 2p+2$, the only possibility is $2p-1, 2p, 2p+1$.

During the search, you can also rule out the pair ($2p, 2p+1$) of [safe primes](http://oeis.org/A005385/list).

Answer (score 0):

As you said one of the numbers must be divisible by $2$ and one must be divisible by $3$. You argued that they have to be different. And you argued that $2$ cannot divide more than one of the numbers.

The third number has to be of the form $p^3$ or $pq$. The smallest values $p$ respectively $p,q$ can take are $5$ and $7$.

So the smallest possible value the third number can take is $5 \cdot 7$ as $5^3 >> 5 \cdot 7$. Thus the largest of the numbers has to be at least 35, you can start your search here.